# Work Done of Parabloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have a parabloid surface S

$z = 2 -x^2 -y^2$ ,$x>=0, y>=0, z>=0$

Which has a closed curve C around the the boundary of S, in a anti-clockwise direction.

I am trying to find the work done by the vector field
$$\mathbf{F(x, y,z)} = (yz) \, \mathbf{k}$$

to move a particle along C.

How should I go about doing this? I originally thought the work done would be 0 because the curve C is closed, and the vector field only has a $k$ component. I also checked if the vector field is conservative and it seems to not be.

How should I instead go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundary here is $x^2+y^2=2$ which would be closed, except you have stipulated that $x,y\geq 0$. So this is the semicircle in the positive $xy$ plane. Parametrizing as $r(t)=(\sqrt{2}\cos t,\sqrt{2}\sin t,0)$, and keeping the anti clockwise stipulation in mind, we compute
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}F(r(t))\cdot r'(t)dt=
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}(0,0,2\cos t \sin t)\cdot (-\sqrt{2}\sin t,\sqrt{2} \cos t,0)dt\\
=0
$$
As you noted, but not because the vector field is conservative.

You can see that this vector field is not conservative by noting that if there were a potential function $G$ with
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial z}=yz\\
\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=0
$$
we would have
$$
\frac{\partial G}{\partial z \partial y}=z\\
\frac{\partial G}{\partial y \partial z}=0
$$
Which is not possible for a $C^1$ function by Clairaut's theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. May I please ask, why the bounds are pi to 0 for the above integral?

Comment: Okay yeah that makes sense, I thought it would be 0 to $pi/2$, because that is the positive $xy$ plane.

Comment: Yeah no worries @qbert, thank you very much for the answer, I will mark this as correct :)

Comment: Yeah just one more question, I may be wrong, but I think the ordering of the top integral is not in the right order. Like it is $(x, y, z) * (z', x', y')$. Would it be okay if you could double check this?

Comment: No worries man :)

Comment: Thanks @qbert, I tried calculating if $F$ is conservative by using curl, and found out that it wasnt. So basically, this vector field is not conservative, but has a work of zero?

Comment: Yea that's right. Being conservative tells you that closed loops are zero, but having a non closed loop be zero does not tell you it's conservative

Comment: Oh okay, I thought that if a vector field is not conservative in this case, then the work can't be zero. I originally thought that a vector field had to be conservative for the work to be zero, it turns out not haha. Thanks @qbert :)

Comment: Sure thing! That's important to know